# Changes not being saved to local database VB.net

Tags: vb.net, local-database

I have a problem in my VB.net (VS 2012) project : I'm working with local DB (`SQL Server`) but the problem is when I modify data in table (query `UPDATE`) in my local DB and after the I display data in DB (query `SELECT` ...) modification is well done BUT the problem is when I close my application and I re-run it and when I display data modifications are lost I find the old data (the first one loaded in DB) !!! I don't know what is the problem ? Help plz

This is the update code :

```
If Not arraySize.ToString.Equals("0") Then
    If Not TextBoxSN.Text.Equals("") Then
        Try
            For i As Integer = arraySize - 1 To arraySize - 5 Step -1
                sysconErrorString += sysconErrorArrayList(i).ErrorValue.ToString() + "|"
            Next
            sysconErrorString = sysconErrorString.Remove(sysconErrorString.Length - 1)

            MsgBox(sysconErrorString)

            Dim sqlStatmentSave As String = "  UPDATE device_data SET SysconError='" & sysconErrorString &
                    "' WHERE SN ='" & TextBoxSN.Text & "';"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlStatmentSave, cn)
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Set an SN please.")
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("No error to save")
End If
```

Comment: Before you declare your cmd, you will need a SQL connection.

[damn enter]

Something like this: 
Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    ' Do work here; connection closed on following line.
End Using

you can find more details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @NETRookie He has one, it is the `cn` object.

Comment: Hm, but I don't see it declared

Comment: @NETRookie This is **only** a small part of his code, best we can guess. It's not *even a complete function/subroutine.*

Comment: @Achrez Are you sure you are *reloading* data from the database after you do your `UPDATE` query? Also, does your `UPDATE` query throw an exception? (I suggest you comment out the `try/catch` block and test it.) Additionally, you should use Parameterized Queries instead of *string concatenation*.

Comment: @NETRookie This is only a small part of my code, yes i did.

Comment: @EBrown yes i'm reloading from local DB after UPDATE, and no there is no exception

Comment: What edition of Sql Server is the local DB? Sql Server Express, Sql Server Compact Edition, etc.

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner in vb programming this is my first project and really i dont know the difference between Sql Server Express, Sql Server Compact Edition and how i know theSQL edition in my project ? what is the relation with m problem ?

Comment: maybe you are overwriting your localdb with the original (and empty) version every time you start debug?

Comment: @tezzo Really i dont know why when i make changes using UPDATE query and after that when i display data it is well done !! But when i close then open my app and when i display data modifications are lost (i think when connection to the data base is closed )  i find data that was added at the first time in that table !!!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `Copy to Output Directory` property for your LocalDb is set to `Copy always`; modify it in `Copy if newer`.

This is a good link that explains how to [manage local data files in your project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx).

This is a more ironic link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150224183346/https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx

Comment: Copy to Output Directory property of the local db file is Copy always

Comment: Change it in Copy if newer.

Comment: i changed it if newer but still the same prob :(

Comment: Do you perform a 'complete' test? I mean: change property to Copy if newer, rebuild your application, start your application, modify a record, stop your application, restart your application and see if you still find the modification.

Comment: yes just for information i run my app directly from Visual studio ... I'm still have the same problem after a complete test : i changed property to Copy if newer, start my application, modify a record, stop my application, restart my application BUT just after modification and before closing my app when i display data i sow the modifations well done but when i close my app and open it modification are lost :( !!!!!

Comment: What happens if you run your application double clicking the .exe file in the bin\Debug directory of your project?

Comment: good it work correctly when i run my application double clicking the .exe file in the bin\Debug directory of my project ;) Thnx a lot Bro ;)

Comment: So try delete every files in your bin folder, recheck copy property on localdb files, recompile and run from VS! Good luck!